# Create Debian package using Apache Ant

Tags: ant, debian, package

Is there anywhere that can give you a tutorial or anything on creating a Debian package using Ant?

I'm being told its already a part of Ant but I've never seen any functions even remotely associated with it.

I don't want to use ant-deb-task either seeing as its not actually part of Ant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no task for this in the core Ant distribution.

There are examples for [ant-deb-task](http://code.google.com/p/ant-deb-task/) available in the examples file on the [download page](http://code.google.com/p/ant-deb-task/downloads/list).

Another option is [jdeb](https://github.com/tcurdt/jdeb) which also provides [documentation](https://github.com/tcurdt/jdeb/blob/master/docs/ant.md).

Comment: Just as I thought. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: ant-deb-task appears to have no step-by-step instructions on how to use it, and appears to have been abandoned.  It a real shame when someone puts in the effort to create a tool but doesn't include instructions.